# find road driving direction from GPS data

Tags: google-maps, gps, gis

I have lots of GPS data and the data format is:

latitude, longitude, timestamp

i need to find the direction of the road?

please see the attach photo at a glance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztgvS.png)

Comment: Could you explain more what you exactly looking for, especially for the term 'direction of the road' ?
It seems to me that you have a series of point locations at a regular time intervals, and you try to find each trip segment direction between every two points?

Comment: yes i am looking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your question and comment, what you looking for is to find the bearing between the two points in lat/long, and you are going to repeat this for each segment of the route.

For the definition of bearing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)

For coding part, it is quite straightforward to get the bearing and loop through each segment:

```
var calcBearing = function(lat1,long1,lat2,long2) {
        var dLong = (long2-long1);
        var y = Math.sin(dLong) * Math.cos(lat2);
        var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -    Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLong);
        var brng = this._toDeg(Math.atan2(y, x));
        return 360 - ((brng + 360) % 360);
    },
var toRad = function(deg) {
         return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    },
var toDeg = function(rad) {
        return rad * 180 / Math.PI;
    }`
```